# Attach existing C# method in dynamically created Type, without using IL

Tags: c#, dynamic

Although this question is similar to this question, [How do I attach a method to a dynamically-created C# type at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710189/how-do-i-attach-a-method-to-a-dynamically-created-c-sharp-type-at-runtime), it does not contain the answer I am looknig for.

I am creating a type dynamically, and then saving this in a dynamic assembly DLL, which can be used in another project.

However, I want to "attach" a C# static method to this dynamic type and call it in the constructor. (since this method is a little complicated).

One way this can be done is to write the method in C# in another project, then use reflection in the dynamic type to invoke it. However, this would mean that the dynamic type will have to ship with a second assembly.

Another way would be to create the method dynamically and then write the IL for this. I would like to avoid this, since I think it would take too much effort. Is there a way to take an existing method written in C# and just "copy" it to the dynamic type?

**Update**

I am currently creating the new type using AssemblyBuilder, and ModuleBuilder.DefineType.

I have already tried grabbing the method body using MethodInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray() and then setting the newly defined method body using MethodBuilder.CreateMethodBody(), but does not work for some reason. I noticed that the IL code is only ~450 bytes, which seems too small for me, because there are several string literals in there that would easily use up this space. I am guessing there is some additional things I need to do to make this work.

As a side question, is it possible to copy an entire type into my dynamic assembly?

Comment: Does the method you want to attach do anything specific to the newly created Type ?

Comment: What are you using to create the dynamic type? Reflection.Emit?

Comment: The only way this is possible is via a virtual method. That said, calling a virtual method in the constructor is a complete no-no.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: The only way to save an assembly is via Reflection.Emit.

Comment: @leppie: there are also 3rd-party libraries such as Mono.Cecil. With Mono.Cecil it is not difficult to read one assembly, extract the method body (IL instructions + exception blocks + locals signature) and copy it to a method in the new assembly. With Reflection.Emit, I imagine one would need to parse the raw IL to substitute metadata tokens (and import any referenced types, methods etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A little late but I solved this using Expression Trees and compiling them into the MethodBuilder as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968125/938668) in response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24925943/938668). In summary:

Using Expression Trees instead of having to emit raw IL.

```
var queue = new Queue<Expression>();
var arguments = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string []), "args");

queue.Enqueue(Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type [] { })));

var block = Expression.Block(queue);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string [], int>>(block, new ParameterExpression [] { arguments });

lambda.CompileToMethod(builderMethod);
// builderMethod is a MethodBuilder instance created earlier.
```

This is very powerful indeed and definitely suited for situations where micro-perf is not required using ILGenerator.